# Toggling divs with buttons

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Following some examples and tutorials about HTML/CSS/jQuery, I've managed to create a couple of buttons which will toggle some content based on which button is pressed. I believe there is a more effective/efficient way of writing the following code by indexing the element identifiers or some similar idea. Due to my jQuery inexperience, any suggestions are welcome.

I'm specifically looking for an improvement which uses jQuery (and Bootstrap).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button1").click(function() {
    $("#div1").show();
    $("#div2").hide();
    $("#div3").hide();
    $("#div4").hide();
  });
  $("#button2").click(function() {
    $("#div1").hide();
    $("#div2").show();
    $("#div3").hide();
    $("#div4").hide();
  });
  $("#button3").click(function() {
    $("#div1").hide();
    $("#div2").hide();
    $("#div3").show();
    $("#div4").hide();
  });
  $("#button4").click(function() {
    $("#div1").hide();
    $("#div2").hide();
    $("#div3").hide();
    $("#div4").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Button group</h2>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button id="button1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Div 1</button>
    <button id="button2" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Div 2</button>
    <button id="button3" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Div 3</button>
    <button id="button4" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Div 4</button>
  </div>
  <div class="div-group">
    <div id="div1" style="background-color: red;">div 1</div>
    <div id="div2" style="background-color: blue;">div 2</div>
    <div id="div3" style="background-color: red;">div 3</div>
    <div id="div4" style="background-color: blue;">div 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: On click of a button hide everything in `div.div-group` and only show the corresponding div (hint: [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `index()` + 1 of clicked `button` to select div with `id` that has same index, and hide its siblings.

```js
$('.btn-group button').click(function() {
  $('.div-group #div' + ($(this).index() + 1)).show().siblings().hide()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Button group</h2>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button id="button1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Div 1</button>
    <button id="button2" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Div 2</button>
    <button id="button3" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Div 3</button>
    <button id="button4" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Div 4</button>
  </div>
  <div class="div-group">
    <div id="div1" style="background-color: red;">div 1</div>
    <div id="div2" style="background-color: blue;">div 2</div>
    <div id="div3" style="background-color: red;">div 3</div>
    <div id="div4" style="background-color: blue;">div 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using multiple selectors, this will reduce the size of your code

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
   $("#div1").show();
   $("#div2, #div3, #div4").hide();
});
```

More info on multiple selectors here:
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_multiple_sel.asp

Answer (score 1):

although you can reduce the expressions I do not see failure to do it that way. Anyway if you decide to use libraries like JQuery-ui you can do it by acting on the html element's id directly as the [documentation](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/) shows. I feel it is what you looking for.

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
 
 
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put this all into one `.click()` function. Provideing this is your HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Button group</h2>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button class="button btn btn-primary">Div 1</button>
    <button class="button btn btn-primary">Div 2</button>
    <button class="button btn btn-primary">Div 3</button>
    <button class="button btn btn-primary">Div 4</button>
  </div>
  <div class="div-box">
    <div class="box" style="background-color: red;">div 1</div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: blue;">div 2</div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: grey;">div 3</div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: green;">div 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can use the following jQuery function to toggle the hide/show:

```
  //Detects clicks on elements with the class button
$('.button').click(function() { 
    //Gets the nth position of button clicked
  var index = $(this).index() + 1;
    //Shows the div with the same nth position as the button and hiding all other divs
  $('.div-box div:nth-of-type('+index+')').show().siblings().hide();
});
```

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
  var index = $(this).index() + 1;
  $('.div-box div:nth-of-type('+index+')').show().siblings().hide();
});
```

```css
.box {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Button group</h2>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button class="button btn btn-primary">Div 1</button>
    <button class="button btn btn-primary">Div 2</button>
    <button class="button btn btn-primary">Div 3</button>
    <button class="button btn btn-primary">Div 4</button>
  </div>
  <div class="div-box">
    <div class="box" style="background-color: red;">div 1</div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: blue;">div 2</div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: grey;">div 3</div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: green;">div 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution. I have upvoted your answer =)

Answer (score 1):

You could use an if statement that depends on what id is clicked on versus having many click events. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5u702wxf/7/)/example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    if (this.id == 'button1') {
      $("#div1").show();
      $("#div2").hide();
      $("#div3").hide();
      $("#div4").hide();
    } else if (this.id == 'button2') {
      $("#div1").hide();
      $("#div2").show();
      $("#div3").hide();
      $("#div4").hide();
    } else if (this.id == 'button3') {
      $("#div1").hide();
      $("#div2").hide();
      $("#div3").show();
      $("#div4").hide();
    } else if (this.id == 'button4') {
      $("#div1").hide();
      $("#div2").hide();
      $("#div3").hide();
      $("#div4").show();
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put into a data-rel element of the button the id of the DIV to be showed, then get it on the click with Jquery.

```
$(".btn-primary").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$('.div-group div').hide();
$('#' + $(this).data('rel')).toggle();});
```

I set up a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/apm27tbg/1/

Answer (score 0):

Just give each button a unique id, and give the same id to the related tab.

When a button is clicked, hide all the tabs, and show the one with the same id.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $("ul a").click(function() {
    var thisId = $(this).attr("id") ; //Get id of the clicked tab
    
    $("ul a").removeClass("active") ; //Remove selection from all tabs
    $(".tab").removeClass("active") ; //Hide all contents
    
    $(this).addClass("active") ; //Add selection to the clicked tab
    $(".tab[id='" + thisId + "']").addClass("active") ; //Show content related to the clicked tab
  }) ;
  
  $("ul").find("li").first().find("a").trigger("click") ; //Show the content of the first tab on page load
  
}) ;
```

```css
.clear{
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
ul{
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
}
li{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
a.active{
  color: #ff2525;
}

.tabs{
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: block;
}
.tabs .tab {
  display:none;
}
.tabs .tab.active{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="javascript:;" id="tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;" id="tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;" id="tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;" id="tab4">Tab 4</a></li>
<ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tab" id="tab1">This is Tab 1</div>
  <div class="tab" id="tab2">This is Tab 2</div>
  <div class="tab" id="tab3">This is Tab 3</div>
  <div class="tab" id="tab4">This is Tab 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `index()`, `eq()` and chaining all the methods together

```js
$('.btn-group button').click(function(){
   var idx = $(this).index();
   // hide all the div then show the corresponding indexed one
   $('.div-group div').hide().eq(idx).show() 
})
```

```css
.div-group >div{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Button group</h2>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button id="button1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Div 1</button>
    <button id="button2" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Div 2</button>
    <button id="button3" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Div 3</button>
    <button id="button4" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Div 4</button>
  </div>
  <div class="div-group">
    <div id="div1" style="background-color: red;">div 1</div>
    <div id="div2" style="background-color: blue;">div 2</div>
    <div id="div3" style="background-color: red;">div 3</div>
    <div id="div4" style="background-color: blue;">div 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```